# Magento 2 Product stock alert wrong price sent over email

Tags: magento2

One customer who is set up in the GENERAL group was on a product detail page of a product with no inventory and clicked "Notify me when back in stock". Once the product was back in stock they received an email but it showed the WHOLESALE pricing rather than the GENERAL pricing. Why did the email send the wrong pricing to this user? How can we fix this?

Magento version: 2.2.4

Answer (score 2):

Please check the /vendor/magento/module-product-alert/Model/Observer.php and made configuration according to your requirement in _processStock function.

Thanks